# Is there a way to group a list into sub lists in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Consider the following:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10]
```

How can I easily group these ints by the difference between the being no more than 1?

```
final_list = [[1,2,3,4,5], [9, 10]]
```

I assume I will need to use a for loop, and iterate through the original list, I am just a bit unsure of the logic that will need to happen. Thanks in advance to all of those who help!

```
final_list = []
group = []
init_position = some_list[0]
for i in some_list:
    if(i - init_position > 1):
        # re initialize group to empty here?
    else:
        group.append(i)
        init_position = i
     # Where do I append group to final_list now?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just refer to `group[-1]` instead of keeping a variable for the most recent item in the list.

```py
def group_by_runs(sequence):
    # set up lists
    output = []
    group = []

    for elem in sequence:
        # if the group has any items in it,
        # and the last item is more than 1 removed from elem
        if group and elem - group[-1] > 1:
            # push the group to the output
            output.append(group)
            # reset the group
            group = []
        # add the next item to the group
        group.append(elem)

    # guard so we don't return an empty run
    if group:
        output.append(group)

    return output
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!